# Button HorizontalFieldManager, change background image on focus?

Tags: blackberry, button, screen, horizontalfieldmanager

I want a horizontal field manager to act as a button, changing the background image on focus:

[image: http://i52.tinypic.com/2cgzqe0.jpg]

set background image for HorizontalFieldManager and it should change onfocus(select) and it should act as a button to push some other screen...

Under that HorizontalFieldManager I want to add an image and labels to display some information...

I want it exactly like in the screen shot, there are no edit fields..

Answer (score 1):

How about using ListField for it,Do you want a single component or multiple components in the list?
If Single u can move to what you choose,or else develop your custom listfield

Answer (score 1):

Call something like:

```
getMainManager().setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createLinearGradientBackground(Color.WHITE, Color.GRAY, Color.DIMGRAY, Color.DIMGRAY));
```

to change the background of your screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
onFocus="this.style.width = '260px'; this.style.background='url(Icalorieimage/account/username_text.png)'" 
                onBlur="this.style.width = '260px'; this.style.background='url(Icalorieimage/account/username_text.png)' "
```